# SslStream authentication failure

Tags: c#, ssl

everyone, I'm trying to write something about SSL and here's the question:

I've built things below:

- CA certs (a self-made CA)
- Server pfx, Server cert, Server key (signed by the self-made CA to "localhost")

Now I'm using .Net SslStream to test the connection:(Client and Server are in different thread, and the TCP connection was built already)

Client:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");
```

Server:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCert); 
//serverCert is X509Certificate2 built from "server.pfx"
```

the client's AuthenticateAsClient Method will throw a Exception

"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

I guess the reason is that the Server's certificate is signed by a untrusted CA, so the authentication failed, then how could I add the CA certificate to my trust list?

I tried to add code below in client code, but it won't work

```
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(new X509Certificate2(Resources.CACertPath));
        store.Close();
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");
```

Comment: One way is to drop CAs entirely and write a validation callback that compares the certificate fingerprint against a hardcoded value.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yeah, I can implement the RemoteCertificateCallback and managed to return true, but this method is limited since if we want to trust a new certificate, I have to modify the code. I'm wondering is there a way to load CA certificate in C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will avoid the Windows certificate stores and validate the chain.

I see no reason to add the CA certificate needed to verify a chain to the hundreds in the certificate store already. That means Windows will try to verify the chain with "hundreds + 1" certificates rather than the one certificate truly required.

I have *not* figured out how to use this chain (`chain2` below) by default such that there's no need for the callback. That is, install it on the ssl socket and the connection will "just work". And I have *not* figured out how install it such that its passed into the callback. That is, I have to build the chain for each invocation of the callback. I think these are architectural defects in .Net, but I might be missing something obvious.

The name of the function does not matter. Below, `VerifyServerCertificate` is the same callback as `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` in `SslStream` class. You can also use it for the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in `ServicePointManager`.

```
static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    try
    {
        String CA_FILE = "ca-cert.der";
        X509Certificate2 ca = new X509Certificate2(CA_FILE);

        X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
        chain2.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(ca);

        // Check all properties
        chain2.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

        // This setup does not have revocation information
        chain2.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

        // Build the chain
        chain2.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

        // Are there any failures from building the chain?
        if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
            return true;

        // If there is a status, verify the status is NoError
        bool result = chain2.ChainStatus[0].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError;
        Debug.Assert(result == true);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```